# In Tribes: Ascend, what is the secret code option for?

Tags: tribes-ascend

In the Extras menu, there is an option for entering a *secret code*.

One would assume that this is where promotional unlock codes go, but right above it is a redeem promotion option, so I guess that's not it.

What are those secret codes for, and how do I obtain them?

Answer (score 5):

There's only one secret/cheat code in circulation right now:

**"GOTTAGOFAST"** turns your "KM/H" into "SANICS" ([a play](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W5vt-_cm1Qs) on [a Sonic Internet meme](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3yjltgPuUP8)). Turn down your volume though.. it's crazy loud!